# Include third party data when Rails model is retrieved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Product` model which I just basically use to interface with Stripe, it only has a `stripe_product_id` column.

I have multiple controllers that are dealing with `products`, and in every case, when a product or multiple products are retrieved, I do something like this:

```rb
@product = Product.find(params[:id]
@stripe_product = Stripe::Product.retrieve(@product.stripe_product_id)
@product.name = @stripe_product.name
# ...

render json: ProductSerializer.new(@product, {}).serializable_hash.to_json
```

It's not really *DRY*, and in this case it even works, however, I have similar structures with other Stripe entities (prices, customers) as well.

Products *have many* prices, and when I want to include them through the product serializer, that process obviously doesn't go through a controller's `show` method, but rather tries to work directly on the model.

How can I tweak a model to include attributes retrieved from a third party API, in this case Stripe?

I feel like this kind of data belongs more to the model than to a bunch of controllers, since I basically use it in ways models are used.

Comment: Do you always want to load the data from Stripe (on every page load) or do you want to cache the data in your model for some time?

Comment: Probably better to make a service object wrapper. Adding too much stuff in the models can become an antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this, I didn't test it, but leave it for you, I hope you get the idea

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  delegate :name, to :@stripe_wrapper

  def stripe_wrapper
    @stripe_wrapper ||= Stripe::Product.new(self.stripe_product_id).retrieve
  end
end

module Services
  class StripeWrapper
    delegate :name, to :@result

    Product = Struct.new(:name)
    
    def initialize(product_id)
      @product_id = product_id
      @result = Product.new('')
    end

    def retrieve
      # API call to stripe
      # set fields to result
      # result.name = json['name']
    end
  end
end
```

and in your controller is skinny.
if you calling somewhere `@product.name` in your serializer it will be available

```rb
class ProductController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    render json: ProductSerializer.new(@product, {}).serializable_hash.to_json
  end
end
```

Comment: This seems like an approach in the good direction, thank you!

I'm wondering if there's a way to differentiate between single items and collections.

In the case of requests for collections, the Stripe call could be bundled in one.

Comment: if you need collection, you may want to wrap it on class method something like
`def self.stripe_collection_wrapper` and again service object that will do the trick